# Why is the same C program sometimes much faster

Tags: c, linux, performance, memory-management, profiling

Well, this will be a question without details because I do not know how to explain better. Sorry. I have a memory intensive C-program (a lot of pointers). I have a source, it is compiled by me with gcc -O2. I am on Ubuntu Linux. On start and end of the program there is a call to clock() to measure elapsed time. Moreover, I am using time command to check the time. The problem is that the same program is sometimes more than 20% faster (or slower) without changing anything.

```
$ date; time ./cudd-example-8queens
pon jun 20 00:49:05 CEST 2016
CPU TIME = 6.46
real    0m6.475s
user    0m6.405s
sys 0m0.067s

$ date; time ./cudd-example-8queens
pon jun 20 00:49:16 CEST 2016
CPU TIME = 8.03
real    0m8.051s
user    0m7.995s
sys 0m0.048s

$ date; time ./cudd-example-8queens
pon jun 20 00:49:33 CEST 2016
CPU TIME = 6.48
real    0m6.490s
user    0m6.445s
sys 0m0.040s

$ date; time ./cudd-example-8queens
pon jun 20 00:49:42 CEST 2016
CPU TIME = 6.45
real    0m6.469s
user    0m6.424s
sys 0m0.040s

$ date; time ./cudd-example-8queens
pon jun 20 00:49:56 CEST 2016
CPU TIME = 8.04
real    0m8.058s
user    0m7.982s
sys 0m0.068s
```

My question is: how to explain this differences, i.e. where are this extra 1.5s (sometimes get even worse) spent? It must be something with memory access but how to check this?

EDIT: I have installed perf and here are two results (I have updated them to show also info obtained from cpupower). Regarding the goals, I am comparing scientific algorithms and it is important for me if e.g. one is 10% faster than other.

```
$ date; cpupower -c all frequency-info -f; perf stat -B ./cudd-example-8queens 
pon jun 20 12:39:21 CEST 2016
analyzing CPU 0:
1300000
analyzing CPU 1:
1300000
analyzing CPU 2:
1300000
analyzing CPU 3:
1300000
clock() TIME = 6.70
clock_gettime() TIME = 6.70

 Performance counter stats for './cudd-example-8queens':

       6705,796274 task-clock (msec)         #    0,999 CPUs utilized          
               104 context-switches          #    0,016 K/sec                  
                 3 cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec                  
             30861 page-faults               #    0,005 M/sec                  
       17295862806 cycles                    #    2,579 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
        7361712951 instructions              #    0,43  insns per cycle        
        1228059232 branches                  #  183,134 M/sec                  
          64491733 branch-misses             #    5,25% of all branches        

       6,709414218 seconds time elapsed

$ date; cpupower -c all frequency-info -f; perf stat -B ./cudd-example-8queens 
pon jun 20 12:39:30 CEST 2016
analyzing CPU 0:
1300000
analyzing CPU 1:
1300000
analyzing CPU 2:
1300000
analyzing CPU 3:
1300000
clock() TIME = 8.43
clock_gettime() TIME = 8.43

 Performance counter stats for './cudd-example-8queens':

       8441,824238 task-clock (msec)         #    0,999 CPUs utilized          
               145 context-switches          #    0,017 K/sec                  
                 3 cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec                  
             30863 page-faults               #    0,004 M/sec                  
       13958245339 cycles                    #    1,653 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
        7360082448 instructions              #    0,53  insns per cycle        
        1227803521 branches                  #  145,443 M/sec                  
          64517871 branch-misses             #    5,25% of all branches        

       8,446645648 seconds time elapsed
```

EDIT2: My Intel NUC has Intel Core i5-4250U CPU. Thus, the advice to use "cpupower frequency-set" was promising but unfortunately it does not help anything. Moreover, I get exactly the same results using "clock()" and  "clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID)" and those results are confirmed also by perf's "task-clock (msec)".

Comment: Use a decent profiling tool such as `perf` otherwise you're not getting the whole story.

Comment: What @l'L'l said ... plus you're in a multi-user, multi-tasking environment.  Timing an individual task can be next to meaningless. .. and then there's e.g. the state of thing /dev/urandom if you were to use that ...

Comment: when measuring the speed of a program, the `elapsed time` is nearly useless as it includes the time when other processes are running.  A better method would be calling: clock_gettime() with the parameter: `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` which gets the amount of process time for the current process.  Note: always check for a returned value of `-1` as that is an indication that the call failed.  Note: the first line in your program should be: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  (199309L)`

Comment: Also make sure to disable CPU frequency scaling via `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelly clock_gettime() and cpupower did not help (see EDIT2).

Comment: You don't use threads, mutexes or anything right? (Or calls into code, that does?) No hw calls either right?

Comment: Maybe you have a lot of allocations? Allocating memory is not a linear process. There all kinds of hw (MMU, swap files) and management (fragmentation) algorithms involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern CPUs have dynamically changing frequency, you should always measure not only wall time (astronomic time), but also number of cpu cycles. `perf stat` (actually, `perf stat -e task-clock,cycles,instructions` is enough) shows you mean CPU core frequency while the program was running in line of `cycles`, if there was cpu-clock/task-clock event  to measure wall time (cycles divided to time to get GHz):

```
 #### cycles                    #    1,653 GHz    

 #### cycles                    #    2,579 GHz
```

This is Intel Turbo Boost (2), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost (AMD has https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Turbo_Core). Both are very fast, so when `cpupower -c all frequency-info` is running, the real frequency is low (1.3); but when there is high load from your program, CPU will scale its frequency to higher level in *several microseconds*.

Sometimes it is possible to turn off it in BIOS to get more uniform measurements: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005641.html

> How is Intel® Turbo Boost Technology enabled or disabled? - 
>   Intel® Turbo Boost Technology is typically enabled by default. You can only disable and enable the technology through a switch in the BIOS. There are no other user controllable settings.

Or you may try some magic MSR writing (don't write random values into random msr regs, it may break something, or hang PC): https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu answer by Maythux: "`wrmsr -pC 0x1a0 0x4000850089`"

Other lines from `perf stat`: 7361-7360 mln instructions, 1228-1227 mln branches 64 mln branch mispredictions indicate that program was the same and there were same code executed (no external random). You may also try `perf stat -d` (better is to select some working hardware events from `stat -d` and list them manually in `perf stat -e cpu-clock,....`) to check cache event difference between runs.

Comment: When Turbo is enabled in BIOS you may turn it off from Linux with some MSR writing magic - http://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu

Comment: This is probably the answer I was looked for!
Disabling both, Turbo Boost (using 'wrmsr') and frequency scaling
(using 'cpupower'), now I get much more trustworthy results.
The best run of the testing program among many ones was 9.81s
while the worst one is 10.74s. In both cases,
I have cycles = 1,293 GHz. For the fastest run I have
branches = 124,906 M/sec and L1-dcache-loads = 214,174 M/sec
whilst for the slowest run I have branches = 114,328 M/sec and
L1-dcache-loads = 194,013 M/sec. I am attributing this differences
to the program itself (e.g. hash tables) and not to the system.

Comment: I have also tried to disable Turbo Boost using command
'echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost' because the frequency scaling driver on my system is acpi-cpufreq. Unsuccessful.

Comment: meolic, not sure that boost may be disabled with `echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost`. There are docs of the file here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/boost.txt. Intel's CPU has several frequency scaling options: [speedstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) EIST and TubroBoost of some version (http://ark.intel.com/products/75028/Intel-Core-i5-4250U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_60-GHz - Enhanced Intel SpeedStep Technology  Yes) . And your CPU is mobile, its base freq is low: 1.3. You may run tests under `perf stat` always to check the real freq...

Answer (score 0):

An operating system runs multiple task simultaneously and to manage it, it do context switching from one task to other. Therefore, It's not the time of your code which is changing each time but the other programs which are being called by operating system in between the execution of your program.

Comment: I need a proof for such a claim. And I think that results obtained from perf do not support this. Am I wrong?